# When filtering an array literal in swift, why does the result contain optionals?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, type-inference

A contrived example to be sure, but why is the result an array of optionals?

```
let r = [1,2,3].filter { sourceElement in
    return !["1", "2"].contains { removeElement in
    sourceElement == Int(removeElement)
  }
}

print(r.dynamicType)
```

Either type casting the source array or assigning it to a variable returns an array of Ints.

```
let seq = [1,2,3]
let r2 = seq.filter { sourceElement in
    return !["1", "2"].contains { removeElement in
        sourceElement == Int(removeElement)
    }
}

print(r2.dynamicType) // "Array<Int>\n"
```

Shouldn't both results be of the same type?

Comment: In your first example, `Int(removeElement)` has type `Int?`, therefore `sourceElement` is inferred as an `Int?` as well and then `[1,2,3]` is inferred as `[Int?]`. – An explicit type annotation `(sourceElement : Int)` would solve the problem as well.

Comment: @MartinR, seems to be an error in the type inference precedence. I would expect the results from both examples to be the same. Since the types are inferred for the the array literal in both cases.

Comment: I don't know if that is a bug or intended.

Comment: @MartinR, indeed. I find it interesting in the least. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think it’s necessarily a bug though it is confusing.  It’s a question of where the promotion to optional happens to make the whole statement compile. A shorter repro that has the same behavior would be:

```
let i: Int? = 1
// x will be [Int?]
let x = [1,2,3].filter { $0 == i }
```

Bear in mind when you write `nonOptional == someOptional` the type of the lhs must be promoted to optional implicitly in order for it to work, because the `==` that you are using is this one in which both sides must be optional:

```
public func ==<T>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

The compiler needs to promote *something* in this entire statement to be an optional, and what it chose was the integer literals inside `[1,2,3]`. You were instead expecting the promotion to happen at the point of the `==`, so you could compare the non-optional `sourceElement` with the optional result of `Int(_:String)`, but this isn’t necessarily guaranteed (not sure to what extent the ordering/precedence of these promotions is specced vs just the way the compiler was coded…)

The reason this doesn’t happen in the two-line version is when you write as one line `let seq = [1,2,3]`, the type of `seq` is decided there. Then on the next line, the compiler doesn’t have as much latitude, therefore it must promote `sourceElement` to be an `Int?` so it can be compared with `Int(removeElement)` using `==`.

Another way of making the code perform the conversion at the point you expect would be:

```
let r = [1,2,3].filter { sourceElement in
    return !["1", "2"].contains { (removeElement: String)->Bool in
        // force the optional upgrade to happen here rather than
        // on the [1,2,3] literal... 
        Optional(sourceElement) == Int(removeElement)
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Would love an insight into the when and where the promotion occurs. I'm sure other pitfalls exist where the type inferred by the compiler is different from what might seem obvious or intended.